# Maze generator (backtracking algorithm)

Tags: python, algorithm

**Task.**
To generate random mazes using backtracking algorithm. User inputs how many vertical and horizontal pathes the maze should have and then the script uses this information to generate a maze.

**Evaluation criterion.**
Maze creation speed. The script should be fast enough to randomly generate huge mazes as fast as possible.
The current algorithm creates:

A 300x300 maze is gererated in ~4.52 seconds, 400x400 in ~9.75, 500x500 in ~13.5, 600x600 in ~21.4

**What I tried to increase the efficiency of the algorithm.**
I tried to store deadends somewhere so the algorithm never visit (backtrack) those cells again. But it turned out to be a bad decision since storing deadends in a special array or changing a "deadend" property of a cell is expensive. Also checking the status of a cell or searching for a specific cell in a "deadends" array is expensive.

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import time
import random


def dig(r, c):
    pixels[r, c] = 255


maze_width = int(input("Width: "))
maze_height = int(input("Height: "))

width = maze_width * 2 + 1
height = maze_height * 2 + 1

pixels = np.zeros((height, width), dtype=np.uint8)

paths = []
all_positions = maze_width * maze_height

start = time.time()

row = random.randrange(1, height-1, 2)
col = random.randrange(1, width-1, 2)

dig(row, col)
paths.append([row, col, 0])

directions = ['up', 'down', 'left', 'right']

iterations = 0
in_deadend = 0


direction_to_coords = {
    'up': {'y':-2, 'half': 1},
    'down': {'y': 2, 'half': -1},
    'left': { 'x': -2, 'half': 1},
    'right': { 'x': 2, 'half': -1}
}


visited = 1

while visited < all_positions:
    iterations += 1

    if len(directions) == 0:
        in_deadend += 1

        row, col, deadend = random.choice(paths)

        directions = ['up', 'down', 'left', 'right']

    else:
        direction = random.choice(directions)

        direction_action = direction_to_coords[direction]

        if 'y' in direction_action:
            if 0 < row + direction_action['y'] <= height - 2 and pixels[row + direction_action['y'], col] != 255:
                row += direction_action['y']
                dig(row + direction_action['half'], col)
                dig(row, col)
                directions = ['up', 'down', 'left', 'right']
                visited += 1
                paths.append([row, col, 0])
            else:
                directions.remove(direction)
        else:
            if 0 < col + direction_action['x'] <= width - 2 and pixels[row, col + direction_action['x']] != 255:
                col += direction_action['x']
                dig(row, col + direction_action['half'])
                dig(row, col)
                directions = ['up', 'down', 'left', 'right']
                visited += 1
                paths.append([row, col, 0])
            else:
                directions.remove(direction)


print('iterations: ', iterations)
print('been in deadend: ', in_deadend )

pixels[0, random.randrange(1, width-1, 2)] = 255
pixels[height-1, random.randrange(1, width-1, 2)] = 255

print("\ncreated in %.5f" % (time.time() - start))

size = int(width * 10), int(height * 10)

img = Image.fromarray(pixels)
img = img.resize(size, Image.NEAREST)
img.save('maze.png')
img.show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Claim

You claim to be using a 'backtracking' algorithm.  I would disagree.  You are using repeated random walks, starting at random positions from previous walks; I see no evidence of "backtracking".

## Dictionaries

Dictionaries are fast; their look up operations are \$O(1)\$.

But they are not *FAST*.  The input key must be converted to a hash value, then the hash value is converted to a bin number, then the bin is searched for a key that exactly matches the given key, and if found the corresponding value is returned.

Overusing dictionaries will result in slower code, and you are doing that here.

### Double Indirection

You have a dictionary mapping direction names to direction values, and then you randomly select a direction name from a list of available directions, and look up the corresponding direction value.

You are not using the direction name for anything other than the lookup.  It is a middle-value.

Consider instead a list of direction values.  Let's remove the `direction_to_coords` dictionary and instead define the four directions as constants, and initialize `directions` to those instead:

```
UP = {'y': -2, 'half': 1}
DOWN = {'y': 2, 'half': -1},
LEFT = {'x': -2, 'half': 1},
RIGHT = {'x': 2, 'half': -1}

directions = [UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT]
```

Now, instead of choosing a random direction name and looking up the "action", we can just pick a random "action".

```
        direction_action = random.choice(directions)
```

If the way is blocked, you remove the direction_action from the possibilities:

```
                directions.remove(direction_action)
```

### Heterogeneous dictionaries

Your direction actions are different animals.  While they all have a `'half'` key, only some have an `'x'` key, while the others have a `'y'` key.  This means after selecting a random action, you have to check `if 'y' in direction_action` to determine which kind of animal you have.

Instead, you want to store the same kind of thing.  For example:

```
UP = {'full': (0, -2), 'half': (0, 1)}
DOWN = {'full': (0, 2), 'half': (0, -1)}
LEFT = {'full': (-2, 0), 'half': (1, 0)}
RIGHT = {'full': (2, 0), 'half': (-1, 0)}
```

The `'full'` and `'half'` attributes contain the change in both `row` and `col` for that direction, even if the change is zero for that dimension.  There is no longer a need to check `if 'y' in direction_action` because the same code will execute for the horizontal and vertical directions.

```
        direction = random.choice(directions)
        dc, dr = direction['full']

        if 0 < row + dr < height and 0 < col + dc < width and pixels[row + dr, col + dc] != 255:
            row += dr
            col += dc
            dig(row, col)
            dc, dr = direction['half']
            dig(row + dr, col + dc)
            directions = [UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT]
            visited += 1
            paths.append([row, col, 0])
        else:
            directions.remove(direction)
```

22 lines has been reduced to 13, an `if/if/else/else/if/else` has become just an `if/else`, and a dictionary indirection lookup has been removed.

Note: The variable names like `dc` and `dr` come from calculus, where a change in a variable `x` is often written as \$\Delta x\$, pronounced "delta-x", and later \$\delta x\$, or simply \$dx\$.  Choose more descriptive names if you are not comfortable with these.

### Two Steps Forward, One Step Back

Those `'full'` and `'half'` dictionary keys are yet another unnecessary dictionary lookup.  We simply need a pairs of direction vectors; a tuple of tuples:

```
UP = (0, -2), (0, 1)
DOWN = (0, 2), (0, -1)
LEFT = (-2, 0), (1, 0)
RIGHT = (2, 0), (-1, 0)

...

        direction = random.choice(directions)
        (dc, dr), (hc, hr) = direction

        if 0 < row + dr < height and 0 < col + dc < width and pixels[row + dr, col + dc] != 255:
            row += dr
            col += dc
            dig(row, col)
            dig(row + hr, col + hc)
            directions = [UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT]
            visited += 1
            paths.append([row, col, 0])
        else:
            directions.remove(direction)
```

### Two steps forward

You really don't need the "half" vectors at all; they are a -0.5 scale version of the forward vector.  Let's get rid of them.

```
UP = (0, -2)
DOWN = (0, 2)
LEFT = (-2, 0)
RIGHT = (2, 0)

...

        direction = random.choice(directions)
        dc, dr = direction

        if 0 < row + dr < height and 0 < col + dc < width and pixels[row + dr, col + dc] != 255:
            row += dr
            col += dc
            dig(row, col)
            dig(row - dr // 2, col - d // 2)
            directions = [UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT]
            visited += 1
            paths.append([row, col, 0])
        else:
            directions.remove(direction)
```

## Flotsam and Jetsam

You tried to track "dead ends" in your paths, but decided it was too expensive.  However, you are still paying a cost for the attempt, by extracting a `deadend` variable that is never used from a `paths` entry, and constructing an array with a useless `0` at the end:

```
        row, col, deadend = random.choice(paths)

...

                paths.append([row, col, 0])
```

Remove the `, deadend` and the `, 0`.

## Possible Algorithmic Improvement

As the maze fills up, your `paths` list will fill with many, many positions where it is impossible to move from.  It is easy to imagine a case where due to an unfortunate turn in the random walk, one spot is left unvisited.  Your code will execute `row, col = random.choice(paths)` to select a random point to start walking from, try walking in the 4 directions, and then repeat with a new random choice.

Consider the 600x600 maze, with a total of 360,000 positions.  With one unvisited location, `paths` will contain 359,999 visited locations, but at most 4 of those will be beside the unvisited spot.  The odds of selecting one of those 4 spots is low: 0.001%!  On average, it will take about 45,000 iterations, with 1,800,000 walk direction attempts, to randomly select one of those 4 spots necessary to finish the generation.  Unfortunately, it can take many, many more.  It is not even guaranteed to every finish.

Before you execute `random.choice(paths)`, you are sitting at a `row, col` which you are unable to move from.  You randomly selected this location, you would know it is impossible to move from it.  There is no point in keeping this location in `paths` to be selected.  You could remove it, so it can never be selected again:

```
        paths.remove([row, col])
        row, col = random.choice(paths)
```

With this change, the `paths` list will grow as the maze is initially built, and then start to shrink as the maze approaches completion, ensuring the maze generation will complete.

Unfortunately, `paths.remove([row, col])` is an \$O(n)\$ operation.  It will search for the value from the start of the list, and once it finds it, it would have to move all values in the list after it forward by one position.

Removing items from a `set` is an \$O(1)\$ operation.  Since you are not concerned with the order of elements in `paths`, turning it into a set of `(row, col)` tuples (because `[row, col]` lists are not hashable) may provide a speedup.

```
paths = set()

...

paths.add((row, col))

...

    if len(directions) == 0:
        in_deadend += 1

        paths.discard((row, col))
        row, col = random.choice(list(paths))

    ...
```

Because sets are not indexable, we need to convert it into a list to use `random.choice()`.  Due to this back-and-forth, you'll need to profile to determine if this change is actually an improvement.

## Backtracking

Profiling shows the `set / tuple / paths.discard()` change made things slower.  Let's try **actual backtracking**.  This will change the appearance of the generated maze, since the new segments will start further along the previous path.

Instead of the "Possible Algorithmic Improvement", make the following change.

Replace:

```
        row, col = random.choice(paths)
```

with:

```
        row, col = paths.pop()
```

My generation time for a 500x500 maze dropped in half, but note these are once again incomparable as the maze is being generated in a different fashion and produces a substantially different maze.

Comment: thank you for such a detailed answer! Now my code looks much cleaner. But... a bit slower :D 300x300 now takes ~6.1 seconds (was 4.52) and  500x500 takes ~20.85 (was 13.5). Using tuples and removing deadends from paths takes even more time - 150x150 takes ~4.4 seconds and 300x300 takes ~63 seconds.
By the way I noticed that the less structured the code the faster it is. A very straight-forward and repetative code (not using functions, hardcoding values) gave e the best results :D

Comment: I'm surprised you find the cleaner code slower.  I've run 300x300 ten times with the original code, and revisions 1 through 5, **using the same `random.seed()` for each run**, and found the best time over ten trials is consistently 2.8 seconds on my nothing-special laptop.  With 500x500, the original ran at 9.8 seconds and revision 5 hit 9.3 seconds.  With 600x600, both the original and rev5 ran at 16.4 seconds.  The cleaned code is definitely not slower than the original. (Without setting the random seed, the algorithms run in non-deterministic times  & cannot be compared.)

Comment: Unfortunately, I concur: rev6 (tuples, set, & removing dead-ends) is slower.  As I said, that change needed to be profiled to determine if it held any improvement ... and it seems it does not.  At least stopping at rev5, you got cleaner code which _should be_ no slower than the original.

Comment: Using actual backtracking speeds things up substantially, but changes the flavour of the generated maze, so you may not want to use that.

Comment: That's interesting... But I thought the my messy version was faster because I hardcoded some parts. I mean I had **{'y': -2, 'half': 1}** already in a memory, while calculating **dig(row - dr // 2, col - d // 2)** on every iteration takes some extra time. And other small things like this also decrease the speed. Btw I also made a super repetative version of my own code where I didn't use functions and rewrite the whole logic for every case (up, down, left, right). And such procedural-style code was the fastest. It took 12 seconds while the code I posted took 16